# what can be effect of deleted .gitconfig file or is there way to recover gitconfig file on window

Tags: git, bash

I accidentally deleted my .gitconfig file on my window system from folder c:/documents and settings/username/.gitconfig, but my git is working fine yet, so what kind of loss i can have ?actually i was looking to change    git bash vim settings so what can be solution is this case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have lost any (global) git configuration you have done.

1. Your username and email address.
2. Any aliases you set up.
3. Remote keys/etc. for things like github.
4. Anything else listed in the git config [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Anything configured in a repo-specific (`.git/config`) file will be fine.

Comment: Is there any  way to recover it ?

Comment: Recycle bin if it is in there. Raw/forensice/etc. ata recovery tools otherwise.

Comment: He won't necessarily have lost *all* git configuration that he has done. Some may well be in repo-specific `.git/config` files. Anything set with `git config --global` would have been lost.

Comment: yes i lost my username, email address,That's why now getting error during pull request

Comment: @user3712320 Neither username nor email will affect `git pull` (though remote system usernames/keys/tokens would). But if you mean you committed changes and pushed them and a github PR is failing because the name/email is wrong that is certainly possible.

Comment: Just manually set your username and email again, it probably won't take as long as writing this post.

Comment: @ShellFish Manually recovering that information is easy. The rest of what was in there may not be so simple.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks : - i am getting this message during my git pull 
*** Please tell me who you are.
Run
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'abc test@pc019.(none)')
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (7828 ms @ 1/23/2015 10:58:39 AM)

Comment: @EtanReisner True story but I have a feeling the OP will be just fine once he sets his username and password.

Comment: @user3712320 As ShellFish said, just reconfigure those. I have no idea why git thinks it needs those for a pull though (unless it expects to need to merge also).